# For Loop Changing Letter Size

Tags: python, string, for-loop, size

I have a list and why does the code not change it's values as `['a','t']` ?

```
poz_string_zad_upper = ['A','T']

for i in poz_string_zad_upper:
    i = i.lower()

print(*poz_string_zad_upper)
```

Output is still `A T` :(

Comment: This is a scope issue and has been explored ad nauseam on SO. The variable `poz_string_zad_upper` has global (in this snippet) scope, but each element is copied into `i` in the for-loop. While `i` also has the same scope, it is not the same reference as each element of `poz_string_zad_upper`. If you want to modify `poz_string_zad_upper` in-place, iterate over the index rather than the elements.

Answer (score 1):

the variable `i` creates a copy and doesn't reflect on the original strings, ( this is the reason above code doesn't work , coz it updates the copy and not the original string )

you can try this, basically update the members in the list itself

```py
poz_string_zad_upper = ['A','T']

for i in range(len(poz_string_zad_upper)):
    poz_string_zad_upper[i] = poz_string_zad_upper[i].lower()

print(*poz_string_zad_upper)
```

Comment: There must be hundreds of duplicates of this.